# WCF Streaming File Upload 300MB +

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having a little trouble with WCF streaming a file. I am able to stream files to the server that are less than 300 MB, but when I try a file 300 MB or more, I get an error around 60% in saying "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". This error sounds like I'm closing the connection before the file is finished, but I can't find it.

The client code I have opens the connection, calls the Upload Method, waits for the return, then closes the connection. This works fine for small files.

The WCF server is hosted in a Windows Service, using the net.tcp binding. I've tried changing the buffer sizes etc, but still no luck.

I'm looking for some assistance in tracking down this issue.

Server Side Binding:

```
        NetTcpBinding tcp = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        tcp.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        tcp.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        tcp.MaxBufferSize = 65536; // 16384;
        tcp.MaxBufferPoolSize = 204003200; // 655360;
        tcp.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 204003200; // 2147483647;

        tcp.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

        tcp.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
        };
```

Client Side Binding:

```
        NetTcpBinding tcp = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        tcp.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        tcp.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        tcp.MaxBufferSize = 65536; // 16384;
        tcp.MaxBufferPoolSize = 204003200; // 655360;
        tcp.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 204003200; // 2147483647;
        tcp.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;           

        tcp.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
        };
```

Class I use for the File Stream:

```
    [MessageContract]
    public class DataFileStream
    {

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public String ID { get; set; }

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public String FileName { get; set; }

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public long FileSize { get; set; }


        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public Stream StreamData { get; set; }

    }
```

And the errors I receive:

Exception: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:48:35.9230000'

Inner Exception: The write operation failed, see inner exception.

Inner Exception: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:48:35.9230000'.

Inner Exception: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Didn't want to mention this in my answer, but are you also sure that you haven't exceeded the 10 minute timeout that you specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you have your `MaxReceivedMessageSize` (and possibly `MaxBufferPoolSize`) set to about 194 megabytes. Try doubling it to `408006400` (about 400mb).

Change it to this:

```
tcp.MaxBufferPoolSize = 408006400;
tcp.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 408006400;
```

Reading the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxbufferpoolsize.aspx), I don't think the `MaxBufferPoolSize` will be the issue (but worthwhile increasing it just to make sure). If this works, reset it to your 200mb limit and test again.

The reason for this happening is once the server has reached 204003200 bytes (194mb) transferred, the server aborts the transfer because you indicated that's the maximum expected size. This is by design to prevent malicious use where somebody uploads an extremely large file to clog the server or to prevent excessive use by users.